# How to create a subdirectory using URLForDirectory?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

This is what I have now:

```
let path = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
```

this is the output for `print(path)`:

```
file:///Users/kuna/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/92BD140D-5C14-43C4-80D6-904BB9594ED6/data/Containers/Data/Application/CD9B3821-C536-4B46-B838-259490FD008E/Documents/
```

Inside that directory I need to create `images` subdirectory.

**What code should I perform to achieve it?**

The documentation says about `apriopriateForURL`:

> The name of a directory inside of which you want to create a unique temporary directory for autosaving documents or some other use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let path = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
let imageURL = path?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("images")
try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(imageURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `appropriateForURL` is not used passing `.DocumentDirectory` for the directory parameter.

Do it the traditional way:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
do {
  let documentURL = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
  let imageDirectoryURL = documentURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("images")
  try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(imageDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
  if error.code == 516 {
    print("The directory already exists")
  } else {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not withIntermediateDirectories:true ? Costs nothing and can save your arse if this is a newly installed app, and intermediate directories don't exist yet. Which you are most likely not testing for. Also there will be no error if the directory exists, which is what you want - you just want to make sure that it is there after the call.

Comment: Basically you're right, but since we know that the parent directory exists safely, it's not necessary. And setting `withIntermediateDirectories` to `true` is not completely free, the method has to check if the directory really exists. One of the new concepts of Swift is to care about those things at compile time to get more performant code at runtime.